# Using `synchronized` code blocks with `.wait` and `.notify` in Java

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, synchronized, producer-consumer

I'm learning about `synchronized` code blocks and `.wait()`/`.notify()` methods in Java and having a hard time wrapping my head around how they interact in a producer-consumer setup. The same instance of the below class is passed to two threads; one thread runs the producer method and the other runs the consumer method.

```
    private Queue<Integer> queue = new LinkedList<>();
    private Object lock = new Object();

    public void producer() throws InterruptedException {
        Random random = new Random();
        while (true) {

            synchronized(lock) {
                while (queue.size() > 10) {
                    lock.wait();
                }

                queue.add(random.nextInt(100));
                lock.notify();
            }

        }
    }

    public void consumer() throws InterruptedException {
        while (true) {

            synchronized(lock) {
                if (queue.isEmpty()) {
                    lock.wait();
                }

                int val = queue.remove();
                System.out.println(val + ": " + queue.size());
                lock.notify();
            }

        }
    }

}
```

Here, `synchronized` on the same object makes it so that *only* one of the two code-blocks runs at the same time. Let's say the producer thread wins the race, adds an element to the queue, and calls notify. At this point, the consumer thread will be waiting at `synchronized(lock)` in the consumer function (it never got to go into its code block because of `sycnhornized`). As soon as the producer thread exits its synchronized code block, the consumer thread will enter its. Now, the queue is non-empty because the producer just put something in before notifying. Consumer thread will remove it, call notify, exits its block, at which point the producer will acquire the lock since it had now been waiting at `synchronized(lock)` line in the producer function. Three questions:

1. It appears to me like we are alternating between producer and consumer, so that the queue size will oscillate between 0 and 1. What am I missing?
2. Since exiting a synchronized code block frees the lock which the waiting thread can then see and acquire, why do we need the whole wait and notify mechanism? It seems to me like the `notify` in what I described above isn't doing anything, since as soon as the lock becomes available, the other thread acquires it and enters its code block.
3. Does `lock.notify()` also wake up thread waiting at `synchronized(lock)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are seeing an example of *[thread starvation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Starvation_(computer_science))*.

One way for starvation to happen is if you write loops like this:

```
while (true) {
    synchronized(lock) {
        ...
    }
}
```

The problem is, the very next thing that the thread does after releasing `lock` is, it locks it again. If any other thread currently is blocked awaiting the same lock, then the thread that executes this loop is almost certain to win the race to lock it again because the thread that's executing the loop is *already running,* but the other thread needs time to "wake up."

We say that the other thread is "starved" in that case.

Some threading libraries offer a so-called *fair* lock, which avoids starvation by ensuring that the lock always will be awarded to whichever thread has been waiting the longest. But fair locks usually are not the default because they hurt the performance of better-designed programs in which locks are not so heavily contested.

---

In your example, the starvation is not a total disaster because each thread calls `wait()` when it runs out of work to do. That releases the lock and allows the other thread to run. But it pretty much forces the threads to "take turns:" One will always be sleeping while the other is working. You might just as well have written it as a single-threaded program.

---

It's better if your threads don't keep any lock locked longer than absolutely necessary:

```
while (true) {
    int val;
    synchronized(queue_lock) {
        if (queue.isEmpty()) {
            lock.wait();
        }

        val = queue.remove();
        queue_lock.notify();
    }
    System.out.println(val + ": " + queue.size());
}
```

Here I've moved the `println(...)` call out of the synchronized block. (I've also renamed your `lock` variable to emphasize that it's purpose specifically is to protect the queue.)

You could do the same in the producer thread by moving the `random()` call out of the synchronized block. In that way you get more opportunity for the two threads to run in parallel--the producer can be working to produce each new thing while the consumer is simultaneously dealing with some thing that it has "consumed."

---

Just to clarify:  Here's what might actually happen:

```
producer                              consumer
---------------------------------     -----------------------------------
                                      enter synchronized block
tries to enter synchronized block     queue.isEmpty() => true
                                      lock.wait()
                                          ...releases the lock...
enters synchronized block                 ...awaiting notification...
queue.add(...)                            ...awaiting notification...
lock.notify()                             ...now awaiting the lock...
leave synchronized block                  ...starts to wake up, but...
enter synchronized block                  ...Dang! Lost the race...
queue.add(...)                            ...awaiting the lock...
lock.notify()
leave synchronized block                  ...starts to wake up, but...
enter synchronized block                  ...Dang! Lost the race...
    .                                     ...awaiting the lock...
    .                                          .
    .                                          .
queueSize() > 10                               .
lock.wait()
    ...releases the lock...               ...starts to wake up, and...
    ...awaiting notification...           ...FINALLY! re-acquire the lock, and...
         .                             lock.wait() returns
         .                             val = queue.remove()
         .                             ...
    ...now awaiting the lock...        lock.notify()
    ...starts to wake up, but...       leave synchronized block
    ...Dang! Lost the race...          enter synchronized block
         .                               .
         .                               .
         .                               .
```

Comment: 1. Is it correct that a thread waiting to enter a synchronized code block doesn't need to be woken up (it will wake up automatically when a lock becomes available and try to acquire it), whereas a thread that waits via .wait() does need to be woken up?

Comment: 2. You mentioned that due to while(true), lock switches really only happen when either the producer or consumer runs out of work - i.e. at .wait(). Now, if the other thread had been waiting at synchronized(lock), it will wake up automatically and acquire lock. But if it had been waiting at wait(), what awakens it? Would it not have been put to sleep since the last .notify()? (at the last .notify(), it would have woken up but then lost the race to the first thread and gone back to sleep)

Comment: Could you answer please? :')

Comment: @ion20, Re (1), Yes. That's correct. As soon as any thread leaves a `synchronized` block, that automatically makes it available for other threads to enter. But, if threads are waiting, the Java Language Speci says nothing about _which_ other thread will be allowed in. If your application needs "fair" locking, you can use the [`ReentrantLock`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/locks/ReentrantLock.html) class instead of using `synchronized` blocks.

Comment: @ion20, Re (2), It's not the `while(true)`, it's the fact that the _very next thing_ a thread does after leaving the `synchronized` block is, it enters the block again at the top of the loop. That gives it a "running head start" over the other thread, which probably was "swapped out" while waiting to enter. The entire body of your "producer" thread and the entire body of your "consumer" thread are synchronized, so it's impossible for them to run in parallel. Because of the starvation problem, the only real opportunity for one to hand off control to the other is when one of them calls `wait()`.

Comment: re (2) understood, but my actual question here is around how the handoff happens. Eg the producer runs through the while loop 11 times before the queue size exceeds 10, then calls lock.wait(), relinquishing the lock. Now, if the consumer had been waiting at lock.wait(), what awakens it? I get that the producer called lock.notify() at the end of the 10th iteration but it still won the race against the consumer to enter the loop the 11th time. By the time the producer finally calls lock.wait(), the consumer should have gone back to sleep, no? Does it not need to be woken up again?

Comment: @ion20, Your producer calls `lock.notify()` each time around its loop. If the consumer was awaiting notification, then after the producer calls `lock.notify()` the consumer will then be awaiting it's turn to acquire the lock (it must re-acquire the lock before `wait()` can return.) _That_ is the point where it's being starved. When the producer finally calls `wait()` though, then the starvation is broken, the consumer is able to re-acquire the lock, and the consumer's `lock.wait()` call finally is able to return.

Comment: > That is the point where it's being starved. 
It is being starved because it needs time to wake up and in that time the producer thread acquires the lock once again. The implication here is that the consumer goes back to sleep each time it doesn't get the lock (that's why it needs to "wake up" ). So then, why does the producer not need to call `lock.notify()` right before `lock.wait()` to ensure the consumer gets woken up and then has the chance to finally acquire the lock? How come the consumer is already awake? Since the last `lock.notify()`, it should've gone to sleep, no?

Comment: I see, so only the first lock.notify() is necessary to cause the consumer to begin awaiting the lock. Thereafter, it is always looking for an opportunity to acquire it and as soon as one becomes available, automatically wakes up and acquires it. Another lock.notify() from the producer is NOT necessary. Do I have that right?

Comment: @ion20, Not necessary, but also not harmful. A `notify()` that isn't awaited literally has no effect on the program except for whatever amount of time it takes. Personally, I like to keep things simple. You _could_ test whether adding an item to the queue changes its state from empty to non-empty, and only `notify()` the lock in that case, but it's simpler to do what your program already does—`notify()` the lock every time. I would stick with what you've got there unless you can _prove_ that there is a performance problem.

Comment: Got it - thanks so much for taking the time to explain! You're awesome! :D

Answer (score 3):

Please check the whole documentation of [notify](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Object.html#notify()) and [wait](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Object.html#wait(long,int))

Comment: Yes, I fixed that in my question shortly after I posted, but you responded before I saved :)

Comment: Could you answer my main questions?